# Ethernet works in Live Mode, but doesn't work when Installed

Tags: networking, system-installation, ethernet

I run Ubuntu Installation in Test Mode from USB on my 2007 Dell Vostro 1000.
Ubuntu works fine and Ethernet (cable connected to Broadband modem) working fine.

I then click install, Ubuntu creates partition, copy files into HD, still the top right two arrows icon active meaning Ethernet working.

Rebooted and restarted after installation and Ethernet no longer working, the network icon is shown disabled.

I then Put back the Live USB for trial and saw ethernet was working.

Repeated the installation by removing option "install updates at the same time", same result.

Wi-fi not working either, but I will fix Wi-fi later, once I get the cable Ethernet working.

I am not familiar with Linux command line and scripts at all.

I am typing this question with Internet Explorer on vista and the webpage is not working well too, bit total mess this installation..

Comment: Post your output of `lspci -knn | grep Ether -A2` and `ifconfig -a`